# docker-compose build command freezing

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, docker-compose

after 'sudo docker-compose up' command 
the terminal is freezing in 'Building wheels for collected packages ... '

> Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography, freeze, ipaddress, psutil, pycrypto, pygobject, pykerberos, pyxdg, PyYAML, scandir, SecretStorage, Twisted, pycairo, pycparser
>     Building wheel for cryptography (setup.py): started

i've tried :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install  --upgrade setup tools
```

commands in Dockerfile

this is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /todo_service && cd /todo_service/ && mkdir requirements
COPY /requirements.txt /todo_service/requirements
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /todo_service/requirements/requirements.txt
COPY . /todo_service
WORKDIR /todo_service
```

i want to know the reason of this, if it's connection or dns issues ...?

Answer (score 0):

Building wheels for those modules might take some time to install in a proper way.
If you want to ignore the wheel building then use this command if you are the Ubuntu user

pip install cryptography --no-binary cryptography

otherwise refers this link--->
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/